# How can I get/install Source Insight in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I use [Source Insight](http://www.sourceinsight.com/) in Windows, but now I use Ubuntu and I can't find a version of Source Insight for Linux.

What can I do?

I use Source Insight to look the Linux core source code.  It is a good IDE.

Comment: Do you mean that you're looking for an IDE? Or does Source Insight do something more than an IDE (I've never used it, so I have no idea)? Also, what languages do you mainly program in?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to rephrase your question in a more generic way, since not many people know what "source insight" is. It is apparently a Windows IDE that focuses on C/Java-like languages.

You are looking for any IDE.

One possibility is Eclipse - http://eclipse.org/

There many many more. You can do a search for an IDE for your language.

Whether a program supports Windows, Mac, and/or Linux depends on who makes the program. In this case since the program is commercial, you could check on the company's website. Some Windows software can be made to run on Linux with the `wine` program.

Answer (score 3):

Source Insight works perfect under wine on x86/64_x86 Linux.

Comment: It will be great if you provide a bit more info on how you made it run on Linux. Did you use mono / wine ?

Comment: @Kamath it was 9 years ago... Version dated back - works under wine. The current state is unknown for me because I switched to emacs + gtags + Sourcetrail and happy with it.

Comment: Thumbs up for Sourcetrail.

Answer (score 1):

cscope is a good equivalent on linux.If you use KDE, there's a nice GUI to it called Kscope